# How to optimize this Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, join, optimization, primary-key

Table A has columns (P1, P2, Value1) where P1 and P2 are a multi column primary key.
Table B has columns (P3, P1, Q1) where P3 is the primary key.
Table C has columns (P2, Q1, Value2) where P2 and Q1 are a multi column primary key.

I need to delete all rows from table A which don't have corresponding data in table B and C meaning to delete (p1,p2,v1) from A if there is no (p3,p1,q1) in B and (p2, q1, v2) in B for any q1 and v2.

Currently the query is:

```
DELETE FROM A where concat(P1, P2) NOT IN
(
SELECT Distinct On (A.P1, A.P2)
        concat(A.P1, A.P2)
        from C
        INNER JOIN B
        ON C.Q1 = B.Q1
        INNER JOIN A
        ON A.P1 = B.P1
        WHERE A.P2 = C.P2
)
```

but this query never finishes on the tables where table A and C have millions of rows.
How can I optimize the query?

Edit:  I am trying to achieve what I wrote with the purpose of cleaning up table A periodically when its data becomes irrelevant which is determined by whether the data appears in tables B and C or not.

Edit2: Improved version:

```
DELETE FROM A where NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
            from C
            INNER JOIN B
            ON C.Q1 = B.Q1
            AND A.P1 = B.P1
            AND A.P2 = C.P2
    )
```

Three questions:

1. Is using AND inside ON like that faster than using WHERE?
2. Can "with" be utilized to improve this further?
3. Any other suggestions of optimization?

Comment: Don't use concat, use column references, e.g: `where (P1, P2) NOT IN (SELECT b.p3, b.p1 ...)` the second join to `A` in the sub-select also looks dubious. Alternatively try a NOT EXISTS query

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve (and obfuscating all the column and table names doesn't help either). Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your answer, it already improved the query a lot. I am trying to achieve what I wrote with the purpose of cleaning up table A periodically when its data becomes irrelevant which is determined by whether the data appears in tables B and C or not. Is using a "with" statement instead of a subquery better?